# Disable Angular 2 sanitization

Tags: html, angular, firebase

I've seen a few answers to this question and tried all of them, but it still isn't working. I'm kinda trying to write a CMS in angular 2; so a backend where someone puts HTML and a frontend that renders said HTML. I am able to display some HTML with `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` but not others. For example, I am able to add an `<img class="center" src="">` but a `<button md-button>test</button>` is rendered as a plain HTML button. I also have a `LessonComponent` w/a `lesson` selector, but it isn't rendered at all on the page, I do see the `<lesson></lesson>` HTML in the inspector.

How (if possible) do I display components on the page from a DB? Code below:

**lesson.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, Input, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MD_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Lesson, LessonService } from '../lesson.service';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'lesson',
  templateUrl: './lesson.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lesson.scss']
})
export class LessonComponent {
  @Input() lessonID: number = 0;
  @Input() questionID: string = '';

  lesson: Lesson;
  constructor(public service: LessonService, public dialog: MdDialog, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {  }

  getLesson(): object {
    if(!this.service.getLesson(this.lessonID)) { return {}; }
    let lesson = this.service.getLesson(this.lessonID)['pages'].filter(lesson => {
      return lesson['id'] === this.questionID;
    })[0];
    if(lesson && lesson['buttons']) {
      this.service.buttons = lesson['buttons'];
    } else {
      this.service.buttons = [];
    }
    lesson['test'] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(lesson['content']);
    return lesson;
  }

  doClick(btnID) {
    let button = this.getLesson()['buttons'].filter(btn => {
      return btn['id'] === btnID;
    })[0];
    this.dialog.open(ExtraDialog, { data: button['content'] });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'extra-dialog',
  template: `{{data}}`
})
export class ExtraDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
}
```

**lesson.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!getLesson()" >
  Error: Lesson {{lessonID}} -> question {{questionID}} is not a known lesson or question. Please click <a routerLink="/lesson/1">here</a> to go to the first lesson.
</div>
<div *ngIf="getLesson() && getLesson()['buttons']">
  <span *ngFor="let button of getLesson()['buttons']">
    <button md-mini-fab (click)="doClick(button.id)"><md-icon>{{button.icon}}</md-icon></button>
  </span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="getLesson()">
  <h2>{{getLesson()['title']}}</h2>
  <p [innerHTML]="getLesson()['test']"></p>
</div>
```

**lesson.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

export class Lesson {
  constructor(public id: number, public pages: Object[]) {  }
}

@Injectable()
export class LessonService {

  private lessons: Lesson[] = [];
  public buttons: object[];
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.db.object('/lessons', { preserveSnapshot: true }).subscribe(lessons => {
      this.lessons = [];
      lessons.forEach(lesson => {
        let pages = [];
        if(lesson.val()['pages']) {
          Object.keys(lesson.val()['pages']).forEach(key => {
            let page = {
              id: key,
              title: lesson.val()['pages'][key]['title'],
              content: lesson.val()['pages'][key]['content']
            };
            let buttons = lesson.val()['pages'][key]['buttons'];
            if(buttons) {
              page['buttons'] = [];
              Object.keys(buttons).forEach(key => {
                page['buttons'].push({
                  content: buttons[key]['content'],
                  icon: buttons[key]['icon'],
                  id: key
                });
              });
            }
            pages.push(page);
          });
        }
        this.lessons.push(new Lesson(
          lesson.key,
          pages
        ));
      });
    });
  }

  getLessons() { return this.lessons; }

  getLesson(id: number): Lesson {
    return this.lessons.filter(lesson => {
      return lesson['id'] == id;
    })[0];
  }

}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that Angular doesn't touch the HTML you give it through `bypassSecurityTrustHtml()` - that way normal elements are rendered correctly but the custom elements aren't because the HTML is just channeled through to the DOM without executing your component logic. The browser just sees your `<lesson></lesson>` and shrugs it off as garbage. As the naming of the method suggests that might not be the best approach to a sane solution, I'm not an Angular user though :-)

Comment: Also: you might not want to access your `lesson.pages` via accessor function everytime you want to access it, why don't you save it in a temp variable before you iterate over it `let pageDto = lesson.val()['pages'];`.